# Google Cloud VM keep jupyter running

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, gcloud

some of you might have solved this so here goes.I have created an instance on google cloud and installed jupyter nd all on it.Now i am working on an ML competition ,the thing is i am trying to calculate n-gram features which is gonna take about 2 days on this huge dataset i'm working on.I would like to know if there is a way i can keep my pc off and later on come to check on the progress like if i keep the code ruuning along with the code for saving the pickle file atleast and come back later on to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to connect to gcloud, start processing, then disconnect and have the processing continue, 'screen' is a pretty useful package.

```
apt install screen
```

In simple terms, it creates a virtual monitor/screen/desktop that can be reconnected to, disconnected from, and has other advanced features.

Basic usage in terminal

```
screen  # creates a screen instance
# start long running process
Ctrl+d  # disconnect from instance
screen -r  # reconnect to instance later
```

Multiple 'screen's can be running at a time, can be named, listed, ...

See [this article](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/)